# How to add an image in an xsl sytlesheet in a table cell

Tags: css, image, xslt, xsl-fo

I am trying to add an image inside a table in XSL:FO, but the image is not reflecting in the PDF.

```
<fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-color="black" border-width="0.4pt" number-columns-spanned="1" text-align="center" display-align="center">
                  <fo:block font-family="isocpeur" line-height="12pt" font-size="12pt" font-weight="bold" space-before.optimum="1.5pt" space-after.optimum="1.5pt" keep-together="always">
                   <fo:external-graphic 
                    content-width="scale-down-to-fit"
                    content-height="scale-down-to-fit" 
                    scaling="uniform" 
                    src="src\com\createpdf\image\LOGO.png"/>
                </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
```

Comment: Please edit your question by adding input XML, XSL and your output where you have a problem - that will be easier to help you.

Comment: The problem (well, one problem at least) is that you are using the `img` tag, which is for HTML pages, where you should probably be using `fo:external-graphic` if you are outputting xsl-fo for conversion into a pdf.

Comment: i edited my post.Please help me 
i even tried with giving URL instead of the path of the image.But didn't work

Comment: What operating system are you using? In Windows, you have to use \ instead of / in the path.

Answer (score 0):

You've specified a relative path. The FO processor evaluates this path based on the directory where the XSLFO file resides. 
To remove ambiguity, use an absolute path instead (i.e. starting with the drive letter, C:\folder\ etc.)

You haven't specified a size for the image. I suspect `content-width="scale-down-to-fit"` needs a size to scale to.

```
<fo:external-graphic width="1cm"...
```

And what are the symptoms/what do you see in the PDF? In Antennahouse Formatter, if it can't find an image, it will place a placeholder. That helps narrow down the problem.

Comment: HI Hobbes, I tried with full relative path, but didn't work. and used \ instead of / also..

Comment: i am seeing the blank cell in the table without any image

Comment: Does your formatter allow you to save the intermediate .fo file? If so, see what the code for this image looks like in the .fo file

Comment: Hi hobbes, thanks for prompt reply.. i have a doubt ...here the image was placed in one jar file , for this code, while picking it will search within the jar file or outside the jar file. Is it possible to add image in xsl file when that xsl file was in jar file ?? If it is silly question please excuse me..because iam very new to this things.

Comment: An XSLFO processor will only look at the file system. So you can't use images that are inside a jar file.